# Simple comment function with begin and end marker in C#

Tags: c#, editor

I am creating a code editor which defines certain lines as comment, the lines have to be marked with a begin and end marker. The code looks like this:

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filePath);

if (File.Exists(newFilePath))
    File.Delete(newFilePath);

while (!sr.EndOfStream)
{
    string line = sr.ReadLine();

    if (line.Contains("CALL") && !line.Contains("//"))                                                                              //look for functions(macro's) that get called, ignore comments.
    {                 
        if (line.Contains("WAIT('DI'")||line.Contains("WAIT('DO'"))                                                                 //Comment the line when it contains any of these
            CommentOverride(line, newFilePath);

        else                                                                                                                        //if none of the above, writeline but give error message
            WriteLine(line, newFilePath);
    }
}

private void CommentOverride(string code, string filePath)
{
    WriteLineToFile("    :  ! BEGIN OVERRIDE COMMENT ;", filePath);
    string commentedLine = code.Insert(5, "//");
    WriteLineToFile(commentedLine, filePath);
    WriteLineToFile("    :  ! END OVERRIDE COMMENT ;", filePath);
}
```

When there are multiple lines that need to be commented in a row, each line will get its own begin and end marker. This will result in a lot more code than is needed. Now I tried using the streamreader to read the next line and check it in advance. But this way I cant check the line again. I tried using another streamreader to only read the next line, but this way streamreader sr will still find the next line and will comment it again. resulting in the line commented twice.

I might just overlook the obvious solution but I have not been able to figure out how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably a good way to do this is hold a state outside of the while loop and then mark it as active when you're overriding:

```
bool overrideActive = false;
while (!sr.EndOfStream)
{
    string line = sr.ReadLine();

    if (line.Contains("CALL") && !line.Contains("//"))
    {                 
        if (line.Contains("WAIT('DI'")||line.Contains("WAIT('DO'"))
        {
            CommentOverride(line, newFilePath, overrideActive);
            overrideActive = true;
        }
        else
        {
            WriteLine(line, newFilePath);
            overrideActive = false;
        }
    }
}

private void CommentOverride(string code, string filePath, bool overrideActive)
{
    if (!overrideActive)
    {
        WriteLineToFile("    :  ! BEGIN OVERRIDE COMMENT ;", filePath);
    }
    string commentedLine = code.Insert(5, "//");
    WriteLineToFile(commentedLine, filePath);
    if (!overrideActive)
    {
        WriteLineToFile("    :  ! END OVERRIDE COMMENT ;", filePath);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but with two lines to be commented in a row this will result in: 
!begin override;
//CODE;
!end override;
//CODE;

Instead of : !begin override;
//CODE;
//CODE;
!end override;

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it thanks to your post. It looks like this:

```
    private void CommentOverride(string code, string filePath, int lineNumber, string inputFilePath)
    {
        if (!overrideActive)
        {
            WriteLineToFile("    :  ! BEGIN OVERRIDE COMMENT ;", filePath);
            overrideActive = true;
        }

        string commentedLine = code.Insert(5, "//");
        WriteLineToFile(commentedLine, filePath);

        string nextLine = GetLine(inputFilePath, lineNumber + 1);
        if ((!nextLine.Contains("WAIT('DI'") && !nextLine.Contains("WAIT('DO'")))
            overrideActive = false;

        if(!overrideActive)
            WriteLineToFile("    :  ! END OVERRIDE COMMENT ;", filePath);
    }
```

Thank You!